# Change mouse pointer on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

I'm currently working on a project that involves elements where a custom mouse pointer will be used. The code that I'm using for that function is simple just:

```
.hand {
    cursor:url(/images/cursor1.gif);
}
```

Now to my question:
- I was just wondering (as the title says) if there are anyway that I can make the cursor change to cursor2.gif when you click inside the div-class "hand" (?).

Comment: Are you using plain JavaScript or jQuery to handle this click?

Comment: Do you want the cursor to change only while the mouse button is down, or do you want it to change (semi-) permanently after the user clicks?

Comment: @Adrian - semi, but it should work as well as long the mouse is down.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`:active` psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3aactive):

```
.hand:active {
    cursor: url('/imgages/cursor1.gif');
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, but the only problem is that as soon as I click inside .hand cursor2 appears, and disappears just as quick. Here's my CSS:

`.hand {
 width: 1500px;
 height: 500px;
 background: pink;
 cursor:url(/images/cursor1.gif), none;

}

.hand:active {
    cursor: url(/images/cursor2.gif), none;
}`

Comment: There's a minor typo: 'imgages'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery

```
(function(){
$hand = $('.hand');
$hand.click(function() {
    $hand.css('cursor','url(YOURGIF.GIF)');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I gather the difficulty is that you need the cursor to stayed changed *after* you have clicked, not just while the button is depressed.

Does this work for you?

```
function toggle(){

    var body = document.body; 
    body.id = ( body.id ) ? body.id : 'body_id'; // ffox

    body.use_custom_cursor = !body.use_custom_cursor;

    body.style.cursor = body.use_custom_cursor ? 'url(/images/cursor1.gif)' : 'auto';

}
```

and then...

```
<div onclick="toggle()">Target</div>
```

I've only tested with Webkit and Firefox, not sure if IE likes it.

Comment: The 'ffox' line is required to override a default CSS cursor rule that Mozilla use: "body:not([id])". I just give the body an id if it doesn't already have one. It doesn't need to be 'body_id', it can be anything.